# How to applied Thrift Server on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, thrift

I'm using Apache Thrift to create an Apache Thrift Server on Windows Phone 8.1 apps and using Console application on Windows as an Apache Thrift Client.
I created a IDL thrift file very simple like this:

```
service Auto {
    void ClickButton(1: string content);
}
```

More specific, I want to use my console application to call the ClickButton method in my WP apps automatically. But when I create a Server on my WP apps like this:

```
try
            {
                AutoHandler handler = new AutoHandler();
                Common.Auto.Processor processor = new Common.Auto.Processor(handler);
                TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
                TServer server = new TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport);                
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("....");
                server.Serve();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
            }
```

and I got the exception was:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

But when I try to add the System.dll assembly, I got the error message like: this assemby added automatically into my project. 
So how can I do to implement my think into application. 
I tried to create 2 samples application based on Console application, it was OK for me by using this link: http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/csharp and I self-applied some others application successfully. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I can at least confirm Thrift works on Windows Phone 7.x. I never tried 8.x on my own, so I can't confirm that with my hand on my heart. Note that [there is a separate project file for the Windows Phone Thrift C# library](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/csharp/src/Thrift.WP7.csproj) to be used, because the standard one will not work.

Next, the C# library for Windows Phone is not designed to have a Thrift **server** running, **only clients**. For what I know a Thrift server is not possible due to technical limitations with WP 7.x, however I don't know whether these limitations still apply to WP 8.x, so it *might* be possible to do that. If you manage to get a server running on Windows Phone 8.x, we would be very interested in your contribution.